# Javascript regex for hashtag with number only

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match these kind of hashtag pattern `#1`, `#4321`, `#1000` and not:

- `#01` (with leading zero)
- `#1aa` (has alphabetical char)

But special character like comma, period, colon after the number is fine, such as `#1.`. Think of it as hashtag at the end of the sentence or phrase. Basically treat these as whitespace.

Basically just `#` and a number.

My code below doesn't meet requirement because it takes leading zero and it has an ugly space at the end. Although I can always trim the result but doesn't feel it's the right way to do it

```
reg = new RegExp(/#[0-9]+ /g);   
var result;
while((result = reg.exec("hyha #12  gfdg #01 aa #2e #1. #101")) !== null) {
    alert("\"" + result + "\"");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/d3TpJ/

That string there should just match `#12`, `#1` and `#101`

Please help to suggest better RegEx string than I had. Thanks.

Comment: NB: `new RegExp` is redundant and is intended for when you have a string containing the regexp - as you already have a regexp literal just use `reg = / ... /g`

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regex like:

```
#[1-9]\d*\b
```

Code example:

```
var re = /#[1-9]\d*\b/g;
var str = "#1 hyha #12 #0123 #5 gfdg #2e ";
var matches = str.match(re); // = ["#1", "#12", "#5"]
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as `#\d+\b`?

Comment: @Butt4cak3, it is not. Your suggestion would match `#0123`, which OP didn't want.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
reg = /(#[1-9]\d*)(?: |\z)/g;
```

Notice the capturing group `(...)` for the hash and number, and the non capturing `(?: ..)` to match the number only if it is followed by a white space or end of string. Use this if you dont want to catch strings like `#1` in `#1.`. Otherwise the other answer is better.

Then you have to get the captured group from the match iterating over something like this:

```
myString = 'hyha #12  gfdg #01 aa #2e #1. #101';
match = reg.exec(myString);
alert(match[1]);
```

**EDIT**

Whenever you are working with regexps, you should use some kind of tool. For desktop for instance you can use `The regex coach` and online you can try this [regex101](http://regex101.com/)

For instance: http://regex101.com/r/zY0bQ8